# Faster way to access a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to find a fast way to access a defaultdict(list). My current code is as follows:

```
import math

index = {str:[(id, int), (id, int)]}

def myfunc(docID, index):
    x = 0
    for str, tuple in index.items():
        for item in tuple:
            if item[0] == docID:
                x += entry[1] ** 2
    result = math.sqrt(sumOfItems)
    return result
```

The task is to compare two numbers and if they match, continue.
One number (docID) is passed to the function, the other number is stored in a tuple inside a list inside a dictionary. The goal is to iterate over the list inside the dictionary as fast as possible.

My options of storing my data differently (i.e. in a less nested way) are limited, but if that's what makes the key difference, I need to rethink the storage process.

Thanks in advance for any tips, improvements, recommendations, whatever!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you change your storage option slightly you will get a big advantage:

```
index = {
    str: {
      id: [int, int, int],
      id: [int, int, int]
  },
    str: {
      id: [int, int, int],
      id: [int, int, int]
  },
    str: {
      id: [int, int, int],
      id: [int, int, int]
  }
}
```

in this way you need to iterate over the first level of keys and then simply accumulate `x+= sum(index[key][id])`

Important moment here is that each inner dictionary must be a defaultdict, otherwise if you try accessing a missing key you will get an error

Comment: So if I use that method and the current id isn't present, I have to make the loop continue right? Or will it do that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You best approach is to convert dict values into list to comfortably slice it, here is my few lines but fast approach

```
ind = {"str": [("elem", 33), ("elem", 77)]}

x = list(ind.values())

print(x[0][0][1], x[0][1][1])
```

output

```
33 77
```